# How to kill a Marathon instance after duration?

Tags: marathon

I need a Marathon app (Docker container in this case) that is created on demand, then goes away (normal SIGTERM) after a configurable amount of time.

What is the best way to implement this? With a health check hack?

I initially turned to the [API protos](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/blob/master/src/main/proto/marathon.proto), but found nothing obvious there.